# scala: creating File object using inputstream

Tags: java, spring, scala

I am trying to write a unit test in scala. In it I am trying to mock a method. Method expects a list of File objects. So I create some File objects for some dummy files which I have placed in resources folder. And it all works fine locally. Underlying framework used is spring.

```
val file= new ClassPathResource("input/mock.txt").getFile
```

input folder is in src/test/resources

But in jenkins build, there is an issue. As dummy files are read from jar, it fails with:

> FileNotFoundException[class path resource [input/mock.txt] cannot be resolved to absolute file path

Some SO answers about this error tell that I need to use:

```
new ClassPathResource(filename).getInputStream()
```

But I need to create a File object from inputstream. I am not sure if API provides this facility.

How can I tackle it?

Comment: Not sure if this is a possibility, but you can create the files in your test method (e.g. in a temp directory) if the contents doesn't matter. And then use the `File` constructor with the path instead of the `ClassPathResource`

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the test resource folder to the jar ? Jenkins should have not problem extracting the contents of the jar.